# Ignite CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory using Enum fields

Tags: ignite

I am to using the CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory

I want to have a VARCHAR field in the database which maps to an Enum in Java.

The way I am trying to achieve this is something like the following. I want the application code to work with the enum, but the persistence to use the string so that it is human readable in the database. I do not want to use int values in the database.

This seems to work fine for creating new objects, but not for reading them out. It seems that it tries to set the field directly, and the setter (setSideAsString) is not called. Of course there is no field called sideAsString. Should this work? Any suggestions?

Here is the code excerpt
In some application code I would do something like

```
trade.setSide(OrderSide.Buy)
```

And this will persist fine. I can read "Buy" in the side column as a VARCHAR.

In Trade

```
private OrderSide side; // OrderSide is an enum with Buy,Sell
public OrderSide getSide() {
    return side;
}
public void setSide(OrderSide side) {
    this.side = side;
}
public String getSideAsString() {
    return this.side.name();
}
public void setSideAsString(String s) {
    this.side = OrderSide.valueOf(s);
}
```

Now when configuring the store, I do this

```
Collection<JdbcTypeField> vals = new ArrayList<>();
vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "side", String.class, "sideAsString"));
```

After a clean start, If I query Trade using Ignite SQL query, and call trade.getSide() it will be null. Other (directly mapped) columns are fine.

Thanks,

Gordon

Answer (score 1):

BinaryMarshaller deserialize only fields which used in query.

Please try to use OptimizedMarshaller:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();  
...
cfg.setMarshaller(new OptimizedMarshaller());
```

Here's [the ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4548) for support enum mapping in CacheJdbcPojoStore.

Comment: Support for enum mapping in CacheJdbcPojoStore was merged to master